# Is it possible to fire complete in simplecrawler(npm) manually?

Tags: node.js, npm

I am using [Simplecrawler](https://github.com/simplecrawler/simplecrawler). I would like to capture only 50 URLs. Unfortunately, crawler.maxDepth is not solving the problem of finding exact count/number of pages. Any possible way to achieve this ? 
Can we fire the complete event manually ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got the answer myself.

We can add the following as the exit condition.

```
 var maxNumPages = 50;
  crawler.addFetchCondition(function(queueItem) {
    return crawler.queue.length < maxNumPages;
  });
```

`maxNumPages` will take the count of pages to be fetched.